# How to upgrade WSO2 Governance Registry from 4.6.0 to 5.4.0 [Latest]

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

We have a requirement of upgrading our Governance Registry server from 4.6.0 to 5.4.0.

While surfing across WSO2 blogs found that we need to upgrade in incremental order. From 4.6.0 to 5.0, then 5.0.0 to 5.0.1, then 5.0.1 to 5.1.0, then 5.1.0 to 5.2.0, then 5.2.0 to 5.3.0 and then finally 5.3.0 to 5.4.0.

Should I upgrade in the above order or can I skip up-gradation of any servers in between or do I have any updater patcher so that manually I can move from 4.6 to 5.4.

Any ideas?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade gradually from each version. 
(From 4.6.0 to 5.0, then 5.0.0 to 5.0.1, then 5.0.1 to 5.1.0, then 5.1.0 to 5.2.0, then 5.2.0 to 5.3.0 and then finally 5.3.0 to 5.4.0.)

This is due to the db, schema and API changes. Each version is built from the previous version. Therefore you can't skip any version upgrade.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance540/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release